# How to enable local Account Lockout Policies through PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt, gpo

Documentation link: [Allow Administrator account lockout](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5020282-account-lockout-available-for-built-in-local-administrators-bce45c4d-f28d-43ad-b6fe-70156cb2dc00#:%7E:text=This%20policy%20can%20be%20found,built%2Din%20local%20Administrator%20account.)

Microsoft introduced a new feature and I can't seem to figure out how to enable it through the cli.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts? I tried tracking the registry changes with procmon, but didn't have much luck pinpointing which keys where changed.

[image: Commands that work for all other policies]

So far I have been able to configure all of the policies under *Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Account Lockout Policies* - Except for "Allow Administrator account lockout"

The goal is to enable "Allow Administrator account lockout"

Comment: This is not a new feature. It's been around for over a decade. Also, why is this tagged PowerShell, when it's not a PowerShell code? You are using cmd.exe command to run a Windows executable. Are you saying you have to this command using cmd.exe and it worked, then tried in on the PS shell and it did not? Running executables via PowerShell is well documented here: [TechNet Wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx).

Comment: tagged it as both since I can have it executed in either cmd or powershell. 

My issue is that I can't find the command to set "Allow Administrator account lockout" to enabled

Comment: Understood, but still as demo'd, you can do this in either, exactly the same way.  However, note that in the ```net accounts /?``` command I demo'd that setting is not there, thus, not an option. Despite the fact that the ***Local Security Policy*** lists it there. Much of this stuff is just Registry Settings, so, one can just locate the registry key and modify it directly. One can use the MS Sysinternals (registry) tools to see where that key is. You run the tools. manually change the key(s), and look for what changed and where. Note that```secedit.exe`` in the OS is an option also.

Comment: [registry 'allow administrator account lockout'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=registry+%27allow+administrator+account+lockout%27&t=h_&ia=web).

Comment: Yeah I know it's not an option under net accounts, thus why I am on here asking for help. I noted that I did attempt to check registry key changes with procmon which is actually the replacement for regmon under sysinternals. However, I couldn't pin point the keys that were being changed. Even with filtering events.

Comment: Also, what OS version are you using this on? ***By default in recent Win10 updates, this setting is enabled by default*** and has been the default in Windows 11 earlier this year. This setting is about the built-in admin and RDP connections as MS docs explain.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, if I were you, I'd just use a reference machine, change the setting there, then export that policy to import to other target machines.

Using Secedit.exe at cmd.exe or PowerShell.

```
secedit.exe /export /cfg "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\security-policy.inf"

secedit.exe /configure /db "$env:windir\security\local.sdb" /cfg "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\security-policy.inf"
```

Using the normal GUI effort.

[image]

```
[Unicode]
Unicode=yes
[System Access]
MinimumPasswordAge = 0
MaximumPasswordAge = 42
MinimumPasswordLength = 0
PasswordComplexity = 0
PasswordHistorySize = 0
LockoutBadCount = 10
ResetLockoutCount = 10
LockoutDuration = 10
AllowAdministratorLockout = 1
RequireLogonToChangePassword = 0
ForceLogoffWhenHourExpire = 0
NewAdministratorName = "Administrator"
NewGuestName = "Guest"
ClearTextPassword = 0
LSAAnonymousNameLookup = 0
EnableAdminAccount = 0
EnableGuestAccount = 0
[Event Audit]
AuditSystemEvents = 0
AuditLogonEvents = 0
AuditObjectAccess = 0
AuditPrivilegeUse = 0
AuditPolicyChange = 0
AuditAccountManage = 0
AuditProcessTracking = 0
AuditDSAccess = 0
AuditAccountLogon = 0
[Version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
Revision=1
[Registry Values]
MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Setup\RecoveryConsole\SecurityLevel=4,0
...
```